# knockout array is always 0 length

Tags: knockout.js

```
var viewModel = {
    foos: ko.observableArray([]);
}

var foo = function () {
    this.Prop1 = ko.observable,
    this.Prop2 = ko.observable
};

$.get("/someroute/", "", function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
        var f = new foo();
        f.Prop1 = data.Prop1;
        f.Prop2 = data.Prop2;
        viewModel.foos.push(f);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

The data loads from the get request and loops through the data fine but viewModel.foos remains as [0].

Comment: How are you checking the length of `foos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

**0)** Incorrect definiton of `viewModel`. Should be:

```
foos: ko.observableArray([])
```

without semicolon `;`.

**1)** You are not defining observables correctly in the definition of `foo`. It should be:

```
this.Prop1 = ko.observable()
```

so brackets `()` are missing.

**2)** Keeping in mind previous point, this is how you apply values to fields:

```
var f = new foo();
f.Prop1(data.Prop1);
```

**3)** JavaScript does not cache length of array, so whenever you use `.length` (`length` is not a property, it's a getter actually) in a loop the length is evaluated in every iteration. You should use:

```
var l = data.length;
for(var i = 0; i< l; i++) {
```

**4)** `ko.applyBindings` is used to bind view model to the document. I'm not sure why you use it at the end of `get` request, but if you want to use `get` multiple times, then this will surely throw an exception. Especially since your `get` is not modifying DOM. I think you should run `ko.applyBindings` somewhere in `$(document).ready(...)` section.

**5)** Finally even with all those mistakes your code should somewhat work. I mean look at the relevant part:

```
for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
    // some other code
    viewModel.foos.push(f);
}
```

No matter what `f` is, it is still pushed to viewModel's `foos` array. If you get the length of `foos` 0 after that, then it means that `data.length` is 0 (or maybe I do not understand what `[0]` means in your question). There is no other explanation. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAg7S/).

**6)** Remember that you access to the actual array by using `viewModel.foos()`. Therefore `viewModel.foos.length` is incorrect. The correct length is `viewModel.foos().length`.

Comment: Thanks, made some corrections and that works. Trying to figure out how to reload with click event. I put the ajax call into a function and the elements still bind fine onload but viewModel gets wiped out when I try to call it on a click event. 

var viewModel = {
foos: ko.observableArray([]),
reloadFoos: function() { getFoos(); }
};